# Why a retraction from a building to an apartment is not isometric?

Tags: group-theory, metric-geometry, coxeter-groups, buildings, affine-geometry

Let $X$ be an affine building and $\mathcal{A}$ a system of apartment. For any apartment $A\in \mathcal{A}$ and a chamber $C$ in $A$, let us consider the retraction $\rho=\rho_{A,C}\colon X\longrightarrow A$. By the definition of $\rho$, for any object $A'$ of $\mathcal{A}$, the restriction $\rho\vert_{A'}\colon A'\longrightarrow A$ is an isometry such that fixes $A'\cap A$ pointwise. It is well-known that the retraction $\rho$ is a distance-decreasing map. For any $x,y\in X$, we can find an apartment $A'$ such that $x,y\in A'$. Then we have
$$
d_{X}(x,y)=d_{A'}(x,y)=d_{A}(\rho(x),\rho(y)).
$$
Here the first equal is following from the definition of metric on $X$ and second is $\rho\vert_{A'}$ is isometric. Perhaps this argument is wrong, but I'm not sure what is incorrect.

Comment: If $x$ is not in $A$, then $d_X(x, \rho_A(x))$ does not equal $d_X(\rho_A(x), \rho_A(\rho_A(x)) = 0$.

Comment: The retraction to $A$ is not an isometric when restricted to $A’\neq A$. It’s useful to bear in mind the simple example when $X$ is a tree and the apartments are lines.

Comment: Also, TeX note: `'` in TeX is already translated to `^{\prime}`, so there is no need for `^{'}`, which only gets translated to `^{^{\prime}}`.  Compare $A^{'}$ `A^{'}` to $A'$ `A'`.  I have edited to use the latter.

Comment: The 3rd sentence of the post is wrong: The claim holds if and only if $A'$ contains $C$. Think through the case of trees.

Comment: My understanding of a system of apartments was wrong. Let me make sure. A collection $\mathcal{A}=\{A_{i}\}_{i\in I}$ is a system of apartments if $\mathcal{A}$ satisfies the following conditions; (1) any $A$ is an affine Coxeter complex, (2) for any two points $x,y\in X$, there exists $A\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $x,y\in A$, (3) for any $A_{i},A_{j}\in \mathcal{A}$ there exists a morphism of chamber complex $\psi_{ij}\colon A_{i}\longrightarrow A_{j}$ such that fixes the intersection pointwise. According to your point, $\psi_{ij}$ not necessary isometric.

Comment: No, that $\psi_{ij}$ will be isometric. I can only repeat my suggestion that you first work out the case of trees.